# What does "sum = map[s[0]]" mean in this code?

Tags: ruby

Can somebody please explain to me what the first line after the hash means? The challenge is for converting roman numerals to integers.

```
# https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/
#
# Given a roman numeral, convert it to an integer. Input is guaranteed to be
# within the range from 1 to 3999.


# @param {String} s
# @return {Integer}
def roman_to_int(s)
  map = {
    'I' => 1,
    'V' => 5,
    'X' => 10,
    'L' => 50,
    'C' => 100,
    'D' => 500,
    'M' => 1000
  }

  sum = map[s[0]]
  s.chars.each_cons(2) do |c1, c2|
    sum += map[c2]
    sum -= map[c1] * 2 if map[c1] < map[c2]
  end
  sum
end
```

Comment: Set the `sum` to the value in the `map` corresponding to the first character of `s`?

Answer (score 0):

`sum = map[s[0]]` can be split into two parts.
`char = s[0]` takes the first character of the given string.
`map[char]` returns integer value for that character.

Comment: _"returns the value of that key in the `map` hash"_

Comment: @TomHaywood I'm glad if it helped. Feel free to vote for my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks Alexey, and I did vote! It gets recorded but not displayed publicly because my profile is too new :)